# Not able to retrieve file that is uploaded using <input type="file">

Tags: html, json, ajax

I am trying to upload a file using input type="file" and after clicking submit i am sending data along with file to mail.But in mail all text data are displayed but i am not able to see the uploaded file.It is showing something like this "C:\fakepath\ngBootbox-master.zip".My question is how to get the actual uploaded file to be available for download in mail?
Here is the HTML code

```
    <form method="post"  novalidate="novalidate"
    id="signupvalidation">
    <input type="file" name="your-file" id="file">
    </form>
```

Here is the Json code

```
    submitHandler: function(form) { 
    var upload=$('#file').val();
    var data="<html>"+
    "<body>+
    "Upload:"+upload+"<br><br>"+
    "</body>"+
    "</html>";
  var queryString="api_user=xyz123&api_key=xyz12&to=test@gmail.com&subject=PostC
 V&html="+data+
    "&from="+email;
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://api.sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json",
    data: queryString,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: "application/jsonp"
    });
    alert('Success');
    }
    });
    });
```

Comment: when you make a post with data, this data needs to be encoded

Answer (score 0):

To submit files, you have to set the encoding to multipart/form-data:

```
<form method="post"  novalidate="novalidate"
id="signupvalidation" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

Comment: I added enctype to form.But still i am not able to download the uploaded file in mail.It is showing same "C:\fakepath\filename.zip" path.@Cuagau